# Reference to void* casting when conversion member function operator exists

Tags: c++

Came across the following example:
https://godbolt.org/g/yYgZox

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    operator void* (){ return nullptr; }
};

A a;

A& getA () {
    return a;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int x = 0;
    // this works
    if (std::cout << x) {
        return 1;
    }

    // this works only because we have operator void* defined
    if (getA()) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why it is OK for the compiler to cast a reference to void* when such defined as a member function?

Comment: If you provide a conversion operator for a type, then by definition it's fine to preform that conversion on that type.

Comment: but why & --> * conversion works here?

Comment: If `T` to `void*` conversion is allowed, then `T&` to `void*` is also allowed. It preforms the same conversion. A `T&` is, for many practical purposes (including this one), indistinguishable from `T`. `if(getA())` is the same as `if(a)`.